Inconsistencies in returned data Axios
So I created a custom API request function that handles API requests using Axios, it's working fine so far but there is this endpoint I call that is supposed to return a list of data but instead it returns an empty array when I use the custom function although when I use Axios directly it works fine and the array is not empty.
NB: the data field to look out for is projects
Context:
Custom API Function
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

const baseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL;
export type METHODS = 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PATCH' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE';


export async function makeApiRequest(
  url: string,
  method: METHODS,
  body?: object,
  token?: string
) {

  const headers: HeadersInit = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  };

  if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }

  const options: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method,
    headers,
    baseURL: baseUrl,
    url,
    data: body,
  };

  return axios(options)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      
      throw error.response;
    });
}


use case
if (auth.token) {
     // using axios
      axios 
        .get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/admin', {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log('axios-res', res);
        })
        .catch(console.log);


      //custom function

      makeApiRequest('/v1/admin', 'GET', {}, auth.token)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res) {
            console.log('custom-res', res);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          throw error;
        });

Responses

Extras
FYI - I wrote the backend code as well using PostgreSQL with Sequelize. feel free to glance at it if you feel the issue might be coming from the backend.


import * as express from 'express'
import models from '@/v1/models/';

const { Admin, Project, RetrievedMedia: media } = models;

const adminDetailsController = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const {
      jwt: { id },
    } = req.body;

    
    const admin = await Admin.findOne({
      where: { id },
      include: [
        { model: Project, as: 'projects' },
        {
          model: media,
          as: 'avatar',
        },
        {
          model: media,
          as: 'resume',
        },
      ],
    });
    if (!admin) {
      return res.status(404).send({ success: false, message: 'No user found' });
    }
    
    res.status(200).send({
      success: true,
      message: 'Admin details retrived',
      data: {
        admin,
        projects: admin.projects, // debuging purposes
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

export default adminDetailsController 




Ok this is really weird, and my comment may be of no help, but I see that in your custom call you are doing ‘then’ twice - what if you just returned a Promise from that call? You are using ‘then’ on the result anyway.

Let me also suggest to debug it like so - print the value that is returned in the backend before it is sent to see if there is any difference there, and also print the incoming request in the backend to see if it is different for each request of these two.

@Ofirfr firstly, i am returning the the data that was returned from the .then function.

also, the complete returned data of both can be seen on the network tab

Ok, can you print and debug to check if the two requests were identical?
